# iOS: How to check if a label exists in a certain area?

Tags: ios, label, intersection

In my application I include a lot of different labels (they represent street names). Therefore I do some calculation to show them in the right angle and on the right spot. Now I want to check wether there is an existing label with the same text in the area where I want to include the new one, but I'm not sure how to manage this. Can I check for an intersection maybe?

I'm looking forward for help

Comment: you can use `self.view.subviews`, it will give you all the subviews and using this you can achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Can I access the labels in my subview like this:

for (UILabel* label in view.subviews) {

    NSLog(@"label with text %@", label.text);
}

Or is this wrong?

Comment: no, you can use like - for (id view in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *label = (UILabel *) view;
        }
    }

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I hope I'll get it working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch `UILabel` from `UIView` in following manner -

```
for (id view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *) view;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I figured out how to do this. Thanks a lot!